# Speed dating does not work

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-pathogen

Running Fedora23 KDE spin. KDE Plasma 5.5.5. Qt 5.6.0. Konsole 15.12.3. zsh 5.1.1. vimx 7.4.

Have installed pathogen and SpeedDating using pathogen.

When I do `Ctrl-A`, `Ctrl-X` on a date field, nothing happens.

`:map` shows both `Ctrl-A` and `Ctrl-X` as mappings.

What must be going wrong? How do I set it right?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I am answering it so that others who make the same mistake can correct it.

If the format you are trying to `Ctrl-A` `Ctrl-X` on is not defined in `:SpeedDatingFormat` it will not work.

Otherwise it should.

In my case, there was a small error in the format.

Comment: This is exactly why you should have shown your string with that format in your question otherwise that's not a valid question. It can't be answered since we can't point out said mistake.